# Proving a group homomorphism is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Define the homomorphism $\phi:SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow SL(2,\mathbb{Z_2})$ by sending
$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ to $\begin{pmatrix}
[a] & [b]\\
[c] & [d]
\end{pmatrix} \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z_2})$, where $[x]$ represents the congruence class of $x$ modulo $2$. The goal is to prove that this mapping is surjective.

My thought was to define a matrix in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z_2})$ and define the counterpart in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ with entries without $[]$. But I felt there something is missing. Can anyone please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: No, there's nothing missing. Although you can't say "the" counterpart in $SL(2,\Bbb Z)$, you should say "a" counterpart.

Comment: Though you need to show that whatever “counterpart” you pick is actually in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. I mean, the matrix with $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ entry equal to $[3]$, and other two entries equal to $(2)$ is in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, but the one with $3$ in the diagonal and $2$ in the off-diagonal is not in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: You should also probably check that $\phi$ is well-defined. (i.e., that every matrix $A\in SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ actually sends to a $\mathbb Z_2$-matrix with determinant $1$.)

Comment: $SL(2,\mathbb Z_2)$ is so small that you can easily check one by one that the elements lie in the range.

Answer (score 1):

By counting, $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a nonabelian group of order $6$, so is generated by any two distinct elements of order $2$. So then we can observe that the upper triangular matrix of $1$'s and the lower triangular matrix of all $1$'s are mapped to elements of order $2$, so this reduction map is surjective.